# Self-conscious vs. self-aware

Tags: meaning, etymology

I've often wondered why the words *conscious* and *aware* are synonyms, yet *self-conscious* and *self-aware* have such different meanings. Is there any reasoning behind this stark contrast in meaning between two compound words with such similar roots? Were their meanings always so different, or did usage cause their connotations to diverge over time?

Comment: [Self-conscious](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/self-conscious) has two different meanings, one of which is similar to self-aware and the other is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their roots weren't that similar:

> Aware :before 1100; Middle English,  variant of iwar, Old English gewær  watchful (cognate with Old High German, Old Saxon giwar, German gewahr ), equivalent to ge- y-  + wær ware
>
> Conscious:1625–35;  < Latin conscius  sharing knowledge with, equivalent to con- con-  + sci-  (stem of scīre  to know; see science) + -us -ous; compare nice.

Conscious was derived later, and came from Latin. Aware was derived earlier, and was derived from Old High German.

That's the reason for their difference in meaning.

Comment: I would also add that conscious has another meaning of 'actively trying to do something'.  Self-conscious has a connotation of actively trying to perhaps present oneself in a particular way.

Answer (score -2):

The word conscious deals specifically with mental state while the word aware refers to accounting for [wares](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ware) - anything material or mental than one owns which might include mental facalties.